# Is FileInfo a descendant of DirectoryInfo

Tags: c#, .net, fileinfo, directoryinfo

How can I check whether a FileInfo object is a descendant of DirectoryInfo?

```
public bool IsFileDescendantOfDirectory(
    FileInfo fileInfo,
    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can walk-up the parent directories:

```
public static bool IsFileDescendantOfDirectory(FileInfo fileInfo, DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{
    // https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/777308/inconsistent-behavior-of-fullname-when-provided-path-ends-with-a-backslash
    string path = directoryInfo.FullName.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
    DirectoryInfo dir = fileInfo.Directory;
    while (dir != null)
    {
        if (dir.FullName.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Equals(path, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return true;
        dir = dir.Parent;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Interesting, you have to compare the `FullName`, `DirectoryInfo.Equals` does not work as expected since it uses `Object.Equals` which just compares references.

Comment: What's the advantage over comparing paths to check whether the file path starts with the directory path?

Comment: @samy: Directory: `C:\Dir1\Subdir` File: `C:\Dir1\Subdir.txt`. The file is not in the directory or one of it's parent directores, but `StartsWith` returns true. I guess you can also use string methods. But you have to handle edge cases. So imho abbove apporoach is more robust and more readable.

Comment: Good catch! Regarding your method it fails with `IsFileDescendantOfDirectory(new FileInfo(@"C:\temp\file.txt"), new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp\"))`. Any idea why?

Comment: Ok, found why, the final \ is not cleaned up by the DirectoryInfo FullName property

Comment: @samy: you're right, good point. That seems to be a still not fixed bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/777308/inconsistent-behavior-of-fullname-when-provided-path-ends-with-a-backslash I've edited the answer to remove them.

Comment: You are now handling edge cases too, which makes it less legible; what's more you are comparing repeatedly some data that won't change.

Comment: Tim, please see my new answer regarding walking up the directories. Your method would compare multiple times something unnecessary since the difference in directories is at the end of the path, unless I'm missing something

Comment: @samy: I don't see your point. A "simple" `fileInfo.Directory.FullName.StartsWith(path, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` would not be enough since it fails already with simple cases like  `C:\Temp2\file.txt` and `C:\Temp`. **EDIT** Ok, your answer handles that ;)

Comment: I agree, it would have not worked without appending the separator at the end of the directory path, which is a edge case and which is why your first solution was better IMO. However since you know have to handle a edge case too, both solutions are equivalent in term of complexity, but the simple `string.StartsWith` is more efficient

Comment: @samy: i also don't see why you answer should not work, although i'm not sure since there are many edge cases considering all windows versions, file-systems, network shares or even linux.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the parents of the file until it hits a matching directory. This will be quicker than searching the directory for the file:

```
public bool IsFileDescendantOfDirectory(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, FileInfo fileInfo)
{
    DirectoryInfo d = fileInfo.Directory;
    do
    {
        if (d.FullName.Equals(directoryInfo.FullName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return true;
        }

        d = d.Parent;
    }
    while(d != null);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the = operand will work here? Tim's answer above gets over this by doing a string comparison.

Comment: @divinci true, this wont work for adhoc created DirectoryInfos

Answer (score 1):

After some back and forth with Tim Schmelter, I'm pretty sure that the following method is valid to determine whether or not a `FileInfo` path lives under a `DirectoryInfo` path:

```
public static bool IsFileBelowDirectory(FileInfo fileInfo, DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{
    var separator = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString();
    var directoryPath = string.Format("{0}{1}"
    , directoryInfo.FullName
    , directoryInfo.FullName.EndsWith(separator) ? "": separator);

    return fileInfo.FullName.StartsWith(directoryPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

What is interesting is that you don't need to walk up the directories to check eaqulity at each level. This saves some time when your file is obviously not in the directory; for example for a directory `C:\this\is\a\path\that\is\long` and a file `C:\this\is\a\path\that\is\also\long.txt` walking up the directories would be a waste of checks since the difference is at the end of the path.

Answer (score 0):

This would be an easy solution if you wanna look up for names:

```
Directory
.EnumerateFiles(di.FullName, *.*, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
.Any(x => x == fileInfo.FullName);
```

Answer (score 0):

FileInfo gives a DirectoryInfo through its Directory property, and the DirectoryInfo gives a Parent property. So just;

```
DirectoryInfo fileOwner = myFileInfo.Directory;
do
{
   if(fileOwner == mySampleDirectory) Debug.WriteLine("Yes !");
   fileOwner = fileOwner.Parent;
} 
while(fileOwner != null)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is enough:

```
    public static bool IsDirectoryParent(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, DirectoryInfo parentInfo)
    {
        if (!directoryInfo.Name.StartsWith(parentInfo.FullName))
            return false;
        return directoryInfo.FullName == parentInfo.FullName 
            || IsDirectoryParent(directoryInfo.Parent, parentInfo);
    }

    public bool IsFileParent(FileInfo fileInfo, DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
    {
        return IsDirectoryParent(fileInfo.Directory, directoryInfo);
    }
```